# Format pdf w/ export or print MSAccess report

Tags: ms-access, pdf

This MSaccess report cuts the bottom lines when printing or exporting to pdf.
There are no 'blank' pages produced.
Both printing and export produce a well formated pdf file when run through the GUI menus.

But, when running with code, say:
  DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "ListPost"
or:
  DoCmd.OpenReport "ListPost", acViewReport
  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\Program Files   (x86)\UDD\ListPost.pdf", , , , acExportQualityPrint

will have the problem.

Ideas??!

Comment: What version of Access?  How are you dumping to PDF?  Is it a print driver like PDFCreator?

Comment: The version is Access 2010, Office 2014 is installed, access frontend is a 2002-2003 file format.     pdf is the Office pdf option...  What is happening is the last line of the report is cut; bottom margin is gone.